# Combining 2 ImageMagick commands be into one script

Tags: imagemagick

What I have is a layer of black text, a layer of grey text, and a layer of colorized text, each letter is a different color, and I want to offset the grey layer 3,3 and the colorized layer 6,6. So I can then use ImageMagick emboss overlay on that single image.

If the transparent canvas is not need, because the bottom command will
be transparent, then I am sorry to have posted this. But I read about transparency being lost, so I wanted to ask?

```
convert test.png -alpha transparent trans_alpha.png
```

This creates images in 3 layers, 2 are offset, and then merges them:

```
convert -page +0+0 $i-black.png -page +3+3 $i-grey.png -page +6+6 $i-colorize.png -layers merge +repage $i-colorize321.pgn
```

Comment: I’m having hard time understanding how these two commands relate to one another. How does the `trans_alpha.png` generated in the first command factor into the second command? It might be better if you simply explain what your input is and then what your desired output is.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so new to this, that there is such a large learning curve, before I can structure what I  am trying to accomplish, without getting scolded for not knowing more, which I have experienced several times. I just want to have 3 transparent images to retain their transparency, which I have read gets taken away.

Comment: Well, nobody here is “scolding you” but perhaps instead of thinking about this too technically you should just edit your question to add details as simply as possible and those commands are what you are using. Without any real details, this question and example are hard to decipher.

Comment: Thanks but I know what I have experienced. I'm told I have to supply what I have tried, what has failed etc... Someone cannot do that until they have a fundamental understanding.

Comment: Here it is What I have is a layer of black text, a layer of grey text, and a layer of colorized text, each letter is a different color, and I want to offset the middle layer 3,3 and the colorized  layer 6,6. So I can then use ImageMagick emboss overlay on that single image.

Comment: Add these details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

By adding `-background none` to the command the background is transparent because ImageMagick default background color is white

```
convert -page +0+0 $i-black.png -page +3+3 $i-grey.png -page +6+6 $i-colorize.png -background none -layers merge +repage $i-colorize321.pgn`
```